# Hudson build project by Maven 3

Tags: maven, hudson

Here is my project dependency tree:

```js
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ gs-messaging-redis ---
[INFO] org.springframework:gs-messaging-redis:jar:0.1.1
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-redis:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.16:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.6.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  \- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:test
```

and here is warning information from the hudson console:

```js
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-22-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/dingjianrui/hudson/maven/slavebundle/lib/maven3-eventspy-runtime.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/maven/lib/slf4j-simple.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
[DEBUG] Connected to remote
[INFO] o.h.m.e.h.SettingsBuildingRequestHandler - Using settings document ID: af65aa4b-6736-4c82-96d7-82a052fb4660
[WARN] o.h.m.e.EventSpyProcessor - Unhandled event: org.apache.maven.toolchain.building.DefaultToolchainsBuildingRequest@4ebadd3d (org.apache.maven.toolchain.building.DefaultToolchainsBuildingRequest)
[WARN] o.h.m.e.EventSpyProcessor - Unhandled event: org.apache.maven.toolchain.building.DefaultToolchainsBuildingRequest@4ebadd3d (org.apache.maven.toolchain.building.DefaultToolchainsBuildingRequest)
```

It seems like that the "mave3-eventspy-runtime.jar" has conflict with "slf4j-simple.jar" file, but how to exclude one of them? cause i cannot find them on the dependency tree.
I cannot find this issue if i run the same maven goal from the command line.

Comment: Do not use Maven Project type in Hudson. Better use freestyle type...

Comment: i'm using the freestyle type, thanks.